# setOnClickListener generates Fragment exception

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, onclicklistener

My App works great when I implement `View.OnClickListener, ToolTipView.OnToolTipViewClickedListener`, extending Activity context.

But, when I extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity` as I mentioned, the app throws an exception.

Code is storagged onto
[Supertooltips](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips)

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ToolTipRelativeLayout toolTipRelativeLayout = (ToolTipRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tooltipRelativeLayout);

        myToolTipView = toolTipRelativeLayout.showToolTipForView(
                new ToolTip()
                        .withText("A beautiful View")
                        .withColor(Color.RED)
                        .withShadow(true)
                        .withAnimationType(ToolTip.ANIMATIONTYPE_FROMTOP),
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main_redtv));
            myToolTipView.setOnToolTipViewClickedListener(MainActivity.this);
        }

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            }
```

**[SOLVED]**

 I had override onCreateOptionsMenu and move all implementation there.

My problem was due to the repro deep in code